# Afterglow prismatic controller reset not working

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

So I recently was messing around with the stream function on my laptop for xbox one and I was having problems with the sensitivity of my controller, so I reset it while it was plugged into the laptop ( hp pavilion). I accidentally did it wrong and hit both bumpers while resetting it. Since then it won't stop functioning like I have right bumper held down!

I've checked and the button isn't stuck and I have reset it multiple times both when connected to my xbox and to my laptop but the problem is still there.

I don't know what to do now. Any ideas on how to fix it?